How do you use predicative adjunct(quasi-complement)?
I made a few setences "using" a predicative adjunct(quasi-complement).
Are these sentences natural for English-speakers or I should put the word like "while" in front of the present participles?

He strolled humming a song.

I gave him a present singing a birthday song.

I made him fix the window scolding him for breaking it.



punctuation would help... and "scolding" needs an object

In speech there would be some intonation or pause to mark the division.  A comma helps indicate that.  (also note the difference between "correction" and "collection"  unrelated words that may sound similar to you, but don't sound particular similar to me)

@user189378 What do you mean by 'quasi-complement'?

@Astralbee showed us a clear explanation of that.

@user189378 Well, you used the term in the title of your question, so what do you think they are?

"He was born rich." This "rich" is "quasi-complement". As you can see, "rich" isn't necessary in this sentence but it makes up for his situation at the time of his birth. Since I'm not a native English-speaker, I'm not sure if this explanation is correct.

In your example, "rich" is called a predicative adjunct. It's predicative because it relates to a predicand, i.e. "he", and it's an adjunct because it's an optional modifier in clause structure. In your three examples, the non-finite clauses are all depictive adjuncts, giving depictive information about the subject (“he”, and “I”.) They are interpreted with progressive aspectuality; for example “he was humming a song” / I was singing a song” / “I was scolding him …”. They are not complements because they are not licensed by a head word.

I don't know the history of the term, but I heard it from an English teacher, and I think you're right, it's called a predicative adjunct.

Your examples aren't quite right.
And they aren't examples of quasi-complements, either. I should add that 'quasi-complement' is not standard grammatical terminology used by native English speakers.
'Quasi-complement' is an informal way of referring to certain phrases or clauses that, while not essential to the core meaning of a sentence, provide additional information about the subject or object. Your examples are just statements about two things happening at once. For example, someone humming as they walk - their humming isn't affecting their walking, or vice-versa.
That should be clearer as you see what is wrong, grammatically, with your examples. They all have the same problem - they either need punctuation to separate the clauses, or a conjunction to join them:

He strolled, humming a song.
He strolled while humming a song.

Subordinate clauses like "while humming a song" do not fit the quasi-complement category because they are dependent clauses that function to provide more context or detail about the action in the main clause.

Thank you for the explanation. I think I'm wrong about the definition. I often see the sentence like this and It doesn't seem to include punctuation or a conjunction. Why does this happen?

@user189378 "using a mirror" is an adverbial phrase that adds information about how the previous action (cutting hair) was done. It could be considered a quasi-complement because it provides additional information about the action in a way that is closely tied to the verb, similar to how complements function. However, it is not strictly necessary for the grammatical completeness of the sentence.

'Quasi complement'? Where did you get that term from?

@BillJ I know, we don't really use the term as native speakers but it does get used to describe what we'd normally call adverbial phrases, some subordinate clauses etc. Perhaps it's a translation of something used in other languages?

@Astralbee The entire explanation helps me a lot, but I want to ask you two more questions. "I got emotional listening to this song." I think this sentence indicates a quasi-complement because "listening to..." causes someone to get emotional, but I'm not sure. What would you think about this one? Also, does a "quasi-complement" complement not only subjects and objects but also verbs?

@user189378 see the comment from BillJ above. This isn't something English speakers refer to, so honestly, its not worth this effort learning about. You'd be better learning what adverbial phrases and subordinate clauses are. But no - I don't think "I get emotional while listening to this song" is an example, either. It's a cause and an effect. One leads to the other. Adverbs and adverbial phrases describe how something is done. So, "I listen to music often/enthusiastically/alone/daily/seriously" are examples of adverbs that show the manner, frequency etc of how you listen.
